# How to separate and assign data in a multi dimensional array via a loop - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array of data coming from another script:

```
while($row  =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $replyArray[] = array(
        'did' => $row['discussion_id'],
        'rid' => $row['reacter_id'],
        'reply' => $row['reply'], 
        'date' => $row['date']
    );  
}
```

I have a function that will use this array **$replyArray**:

```
        //In this function we extract data(discussions) from array
    //This function is called inside disReply function.

    function subDiscussion($replyArray){
                        $reply_count    = count($replyArray);
                        for($x=0; $x < $reply_count; $x++){
                            echo "<br><h3>Data: ".($x +1).' <br>'."</h3>" ;
                            foreach($replyArray[$x] as $key => $value){
                                echo $data= $key.": ". $value."<br>";               

                            }

                        }
                };
```

The example above returns all associated paired data by just echoing the variable **$data.**

What I want to achieve is to separate the data(data in paire) into different variables:

**$rid** =  its value

**$did** = its value

**$reply** = its value

**$date** = its value

The reason is because I want to put them in an HTML design in that function later.

Thank you.

Comment: Something like [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)?

Comment: wow...this function is gonna be powerful...I just read PHP manual . It says it treat key names as variable and values as variable value.

Comment: Thank you your answer too was useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable variables will help here:

```
// inside the final (foreach) loop
foreach($replyArray[$x] as $key => $value){

    $$key = $value;     

}
// now use these variables, $did, $rid, etc., e.g. save to an array or use in a function - else they will be overwritten in next iteration of parent for loop
```

Read more about variable variables [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

According to what Patrick Q suggested using the PHP **extract()**

```
for($x=0; $x < $reply_count; $x++){
    extract($replyArray[$x]);
}
```

**extract()** This function treats keys as variable names and values as variable values. For each key/value pair it will create a variable

Comment: am really confused

Comment: For example, when $x = 0, the first $key is "did". A variable variable lets you take that value, and now construct a variable using that value, so it's like $$key = ${"did"} = $did

Comment: great!!. It worked  but I must state that I used the variables outside  inner foreach loop. so I was successful using it inside the for loop: